# Передача значения name ссылки в volue input

Tags: jquery, form

Не могу решить проблемку. Есть 3 ссылки, которые вызывают одно и тоже модальное окно в котором форма, необходимо передать значение ссылки name в value input hidden

```
<a href="#" data-target="#OrderModel" data-toggle="modal" name="model1">model1</a>
<a href="#" data-target="#OrderModel" data-toggle="modal" name="model2">model2</a>
<a href="#" data-target="#OrderModel" data-toggle="modal" name="model3">model3</a>


<input type="text" name="имя">
<input type="hidden" value="" class="hidden">
```

Возможно можно как то по другому передать, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: и как вы пытаетесь это сделать? код в студию

Comment: вам собственно надо повесить обработчик клика на эти ссылки, исправить `name`  на `data-name="..."` и получить значение и вписывать куда надо. на все про все одна строка кода.

Comment: Кода нет, я тут же находил на форуме другие обработчики, которые подмену делают внутри формы, это не подходит

Comment: Я не силён в js я не особо понимаю, если это одна строка кода, напишите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

следует пометить нужный инпут каким-нибудь `id="xxx"` добавить к ссылкам класс а-ля `class="my-link"`, для корректности атрибут сделать с префиксом `data-name="model-1"`

и навесить обработчик на ссылки

```
$(".my-link").click(function(e){        
     $("#xxx").val( $(this).data('name') );
});
```

Comment: Отлично! повесил вызов функции в онклик и работает, спасибо